# Error método no se encuentra

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

buen día.

Cuando quiero subir los cambios al servidor que tengo en una VM, limpio y compilo la app y copio y pego los archivos dll para la carpeta de la app que tengo en el servidor, pero cuando quiero ver si funciona me manda un error de que el método no ha sido encontrado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Según esto me marca error por los métodos que tengo en una clase.

```
[Display(Name = "Agente")]
public int AgenteId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("AgenteId")]
public virtual Agente Agente { get; set; }
```

Comment: Y la duda es??? Porque el error es de código y aparece claramente en la imagen que pusiste

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta, pero no sé por qué me marca error sí tengo el metodo público y si lo mando a llamar desde otra parte

Comment: /Funciona en local?

Comment: Por otro lado, ¿conoces `publish` ?

Comment: sí, funciona todo perfectamente pero ya cuando subo los cambios y veo me lanza ese error. Y no, no conozco publish